# How to find gzip file is empty compressed file

Tags: perl, gzip

How to find gzip file is empty  using perl

a.txt.gz when i uncompress its empty

how to find the compress gz are empty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly get the size of the uncompressed file, but you can use seek for it. Create an object from the file and try to seek to the first byte. If you can seek, then your file is at least 1 byte in size, otherwise it is empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;
use Fcntl qw(:seek);

my $u = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new('readme.gz');
if ( $u->seek(1, SEEK_CUR) ) {
    print "Can seek, file greather than zero\n";
}
else {
    print "Cannot seek, file is zero\n";
}
```

Comment: This is the best way to go. I didn't think of using Fcntl and doing a seek.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IO::Compress::Gzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Compress/Gzip.html) which comes with Perl 5.10 and above (or download it via [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.035/lib/IO/Compress/Gzip.pm)). And use that to read the file.

However, you could just do a [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) on the file and simply see if it contains only 26 bytes since an empty file will consist of just a 26 byte header.

I guess it simply depends what you're attempting to do. Are you merely trying to determine whether a gzipped file is empty or did you plan on reading it and decompress it first? If it's the former, `stat` would be the easiest. If it's the latter, use the `IO::Compress::Gzip` module and not a bunch of `system` commands to call `gzip`. The `IO::Compress::Gzip` comes with all Perl distributions 5.10 and greater, so it's the default way of handling Zip.

Comment: You can't check the file size and compare it with "26". The file size of the zipped file depents an the filename.

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly 26 bytes, but if it's between 25 and 40 bytes, it's definitely empty

Comment: The complete filename before zipping is in the header. If you gzip a long filename it is as large as the filename + header. And it can easly go over 40 bytes, if your filename is longer than 40 bytes.

Comment: a filename "readme" containing nothing and a filename "readm" just containing 1 byte is both gziped 27 bytes. So dont tell a file between 25 - 40 bytes is defenitly empty! It is not!

Comment: Okay, then use IO::Compress::Gzip. It has to (at least in memory) unzip the file, so it takes a bit longer, but probably is a better plan.

Answer (score 0):

To check the content of a compressed tar-file, use

```
tar -ztvf file.tgz
```

To list content of a .gz-file, use

```
gzip --list file.gz
```

Wrap that in perl and check the `uncompressed` field in the output

```
$ gzip --list fjant.gz 
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
                 26                   0   0.0% fjant
```

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to mix perl and shell because the resultant file is hard to read.